# Add a new row based on the custom image button's current position

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I recently started learning scripts. I've come to a dead end where I can't think of the logic on how I would implement my script where once i click the button it would automatically add a row above the button. Here is sample picture of my spreadsheet I use it to fix my finances. [image]

Here is my current code but its nowhere near what I wanted to do. Kindly help please to lead me to the proper script. Thank you!

```
function addRow() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.insertRowAfter(22);

}
```

Comment: I made a small update to my answer. If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75416283/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @kejer I am having an issue similar to yours did the solution given by Lorena work for you?

Comment: @YancyGodoy yes it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a row above the button you have in your sheet. If that is the case, you can try with the following:

```
function addRow(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //Use this if the button is an image
  var image = sheet.getImages();
  var imageRow = image[0].getAnchorCell().getRow();
  sheet.insertRowBefore(imageRow);

  //Use this if the button is a drawing
  /*
  var drawings = sheet.getDrawings();
  var row = drawings[0].getContainerInfo().getAnchorRow();
  sheet.insertRowBefore(row);
  */
}
```

**Note:** In the sample provided, I only have one image in the sheet and that's why I have specified `image[0]`.

Remember to assign the script to the button by clicking in the three dots of the drawing, select "Assign script" and add the name of the function.